# How do I check what iframe I am currently in? #selenium #python

Tags: python, selenium

To access elements on a HTML webpage I need the driver to be in that specific iframe. How do I check which iframe I am currently in?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that programmatically.

I would suggest to go to

> Chrome -> dev tools (Press F12) -> then go to element section - > do
> a CTRL + F

and then you would see the search bar.

Now let's say you have a button **xpath** something like this :

```
//button[@id='someid']
```

just copy paste this xpath into search bar. once done, you will have to traverse upward in HTML structure to see if there's an iframe tag.

or probably something like this :

```
//button[@id='someid']/ancestor::iframe
```

the element you are looking for if it's in frame, it will be child of iframe tag. So just remember you will have to scroll up in HTML from the desired element to check if it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically you can't check which IFRAME you are in. You have to know how the page is laid out and switch to the specific IFRAME your element is in.

One way to manage where you are at at any given time is to switch back to the default content (top level) and then navigate back into the desired IFRAME. This assumes there's more than one IFRAME on the page that you need to navigate into and you have a somewhat complicated script.